# Why does my US Map crash the browser in Firefox? D3.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, dictionary, svg, d3.js

[image: d3 js map]

This is an image of my d3 graph.

On Firefox, unlike Chrome and IE, the browser seemed to buck when pressed to paint the SVG and would crash. When the graph was removed, it was no problem and the page didn't break. Again, on every other browser it was no problem. There were no errors logged. Only browser death.

Works in IE 10 and Chrome 32 >> latest browsers. Is crashing in Firefox 26.0.

```
(function(){
var width = 900,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([460, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(2);

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "../us.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "../long_lat.tsv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, us, long_lat) {
    if (error){
        console.log(error);
    }

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

     svg.append("path")
          .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
          .attr("class", "states")
          .attr("d", path);


     svg.append("path")
          .datum({type: "MultiPoint", coordinates: long_lat})
          .attr("class", "points")
          .attr("d", path)
          .style('fill', 'rgb(247, 150, 29)');
};

})();
```

my tsv data:

```
0   1
-73.427242  40.871873
-73.996700  40.750000
-73.992363  40.740134
-87.525537  37.942482
-89.564576  44.501590
-118.819400 34.192900
-73.897400  42.774700
-101.886595 35.149460
-71.769200  42.249000
-71.887880  41.807116
-73.991458  40.737710
-78.953169  43.053301
-72.484121  42.787935
-122.615410 45.332182
...
```

Comment: I should also mention that the Answer Code in that link is what the final version of this graph ended up being.

Comment: You'd need to host the complete code somewhere so we can check. All the other question has is a fragment.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Does it work with other versions? You may be hitting a firefox bug here.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have updated to include versions where it worked. This was happening in Firefox 26.0 but worked in latest Chrome and IE... I suspect a Firefox SVG bug

Comment: @RobertLongson I have updated question to include relevant code (minus the TopoJSON for US). If that is called into question, I can provide that as well.

Comment: I think you'd need to host your complete code somewhere as a website.